# how do I link to a page elsewhere in the app from a Devise page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, routes

My app uses Devise for sign in. I installed it according to the wiki and got it working fine. I recently added a "terms of service" page to my app at "http://127.0.0.1:3000/tos", it routes via a static controller:

`match ':action' => 'static#:action'`

I've put a link to it in the bottom of my application.html.erb file. I want a link to Terms of Service and Privacy Policy to be at the bottom of each page. But when I go to the `users/sign_in` page it won't show the link to the TOS page -- instead there's an error (below).

I've removed all the routes in my app except for these (for the purpose of tracking down this issue):

```
   root :to => 'home#index'
   #devise routes
   devise_for :users, :admins
   #static
   match ':action' => 'static#:action'
```

The link is specified like so: `<%= link_to "Terms of Service", :controller => "static", :action => "tos" %>`

The error is:

`No route matches {:controller=>"devise/static", :action=>"tos"}`

So Devise is sorta getting in the way of my routing to this static 
page. How do I specify the route to go to the root of the app instead 
of starting with Devise?

**Update:** in the short term, the answer was to hardcode it: 
  `<%= link_to "Terms of Service", "/tos" %>` -- not an ideal answer though.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to generating the views

```
rails generate devise:views
```

you need to configure devise to use the scoped views instead of the views from the gem

```
config.scoped_views = "true”
```

in the config/initializers/devise.rb file

Comment: scoped_views was set to false (default) but changing it didn't fix the issue. I already had all the devise views (confirmations, mailer etc).

Answer (score 0):

This should work then:

`match ':action' => 'static#:action', :as => :static`

and your link should be generated with something like:

`<%= link_to "Terms of Service", static_path(:action => 'tos') %>`

Comment: I don't think so, the static routing is working, it's only when I try to make a link to a static page from a devise page that it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten this error many times. I fix it by adding the route to the devise routing block

like this( in your case )
**Update added different routes to try**

```
devise_for :users, admins do
  match '/:action' => 'static#:action'     
end

match '/:action' => 'static#:action'

devise_for :users, admins do
      match '/tos' => 'static#tos'     
    end

    match ':action' => 'static#:action'
```

I also leave the route outside the block. Not very DRY, but it works.

Comment: Huh, it seemed like a good idea, but I'm still getting the error. Same error after I added the new match to the devise_for block.

Comment: Ok. Form the error message it is clear that you need a route in the block. I have updated the post. Try it.